# How to create a button that runs a javascript function multiple times?

Tags: javascript, html, function, button

Basically I want to be able to rotate the numbers clockwise when I click the rotate button. I think I've attached all of the associated code. I created a button. It links back to the javascript function. It even runs the function. The issue is I can only get it to run the function and rotate one time.

```js
var value1 = "1";
var value2 = "2";
var value4 = "3";
var value3 = "4";

document.getElementById("value1").innerHTML = value1;
document.getElementById("value2").innerHTML = value2;
document.getElementById("value3").innerHTML = value3;
document.getElementById("value4").innerHTML = value4;

var btn = document.querySelector('#bt1');

btn.addEventListener('click', rotate)

function rotate() {
  var Value1 = value1;
  var Value2 = value2;
  var Value3 = value3;
  var Value4 = value4;
  document.getElementById("value1").innerHTML = Value4;
  document.getElementById("value2").innerHTML = Value1;
  document.getElementById("value3").innerHTML = Value2;
  document.getElementById("value4").innerHTML = Value3;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 20%;
}

.import {
  padding-bottom: 0.3em;
}

.import input[type=text] {
  width: 630px;
}

.valid {
  background-color: limegreen;
}

.invalid {
  background-color: red;
}

.imported_square {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.puzzle {
  border: 4px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.puzzle tr {
  padding: 0;
}

.puzzle td {
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 2em;
  font-size: 50pt;
  text-align: center;
}

.puzzle .thick_right {
  border-right: 4px solid black;
}

.puzzle .thick_bottom {
  border-bottom: 4px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button id="bt1">Rotate</button>
  <table class="puzzle" width=250px height=250px>
    <tr class="1 thick_bottom">
      <td id="value1" class="1 thick_right"></td>
      <td id="value2" class="2 thick_right"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="2 thick_bottom">
      <td id="value3" class="1 thick_right"></td>
      <td id="value4" class="2 thick_right"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

I've spent a long time scouring threads on here and also trying to create my own roundabout ways but nothing seems to work. I can get it to rotate once but I just can't find a way to make it rotate more than once. I want to be able to click the rotate button as many times as I want and the numbers keep rotating in a clockwise direction.

Comment: this reminds me of a similar question i answered: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73535181/3807365

Comment: Lines 3 and 4 seem to be mixed up. Is that intentional?

Comment: The main problem is you don’t ever update the variables `value1` `value2` etc.  — the function uses the starting values each time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function to modify each number upon each round of rotation:

```js
    var value1 = 1;
    var value2 = 2;
    var value4 = 3;
    var value3 = 4;
    
    document.getElementById("value1").innerHTML = value1;
    document.getElementById("value2").innerHTML = value2;
    document.getElementById("value3").innerHTML = value3;
    document.getElementById("value4").innerHTML = value4;
    
    var btn = document.querySelector('#bt1');
    
    btn.addEventListener('click', rotate)
        
    function nextNum(currentNum) {
      // upon each rotate, minus the current number by 1 or reset to 4
      return currentNum - 1 < 1 ? 4 : currentNum - 1
    }
    
    function rotate(){

        value1 = nextNum(value1)
        value2 = nextNum(value2)
        value3 = nextNum(value3)
        value4 = nextNum(value4)
        
        document.getElementById("value1").innerHTML = value1;
        document.getElementById("value2").innerHTML = value2;
        document.getElementById("value3").innerHTML = value3;
        document.getElementById("value4").innerHTML = value4;
    }
```

```css
 body {
  font-family:sans-serif;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 20%;
          }
.import {padding-bottom:0.3em;}
.import input[type=text] {width:630px;}

.valid {background-color:limegreen;}
.invalid {background-color:red;}
.imported_square {background-color:lightgray;}

.puzzle {border:4px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;}
.puzzle tr {padding:0;}
.puzzle td {padding:0; border:1px solid black; width:2em; font-size:50pt; text-align:center;}
.puzzle .thick_right {border-right:4px solid black;}
.puzzle .thick_bottom {border-bottom:4px solid black;}
```

```html
<div>
  <button id="bt1">Rotate</button>
  <table class="puzzle" width=250px height=250px>
      <tr class="1 thick_bottom">
        <td id="value1" class="1 thick_right"></td>
        <td id="value2" class="2 thick_right"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="2 thick_bottom">
        <td id="value3" class="1 thick_right"></td>
        <td id="value4" class="2 thick_right"></td>
      </tr>
  </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add in the rotate button values (next to id) onclick='rotate(element)' and add a parameter in rotate() function that says which element to rotate.

Answer (score 0):

You keep rotating the same numbers so it seems the button isn't working. I've arranged the code so that the function would work. Pay attention to what variables is exchanged with another. This is counterclockwise rotation.

```js
var value1 = "1";
var value2 = "2";
var value4 = "3";
var value3 = "4";

document.getElementById("value1").innerHTML = value1;
document.getElementById("value2").innerHTML = value2;
document.getElementById("value3").innerHTML = value3;
document.getElementById("value4").innerHTML = value4;

var btn = document.querySelector('#bt1');

btn.addEventListener('click', rotate)

function rotate() {
  var old_value1 = value1
  value1 = value2;
  value2 = value4;
  value4 = value3;
  value3 = old_value1;
  document.getElementById("value1").innerHTML = value1;
  document.getElementById("value2").innerHTML = value2;
  document.getElementById("value3").innerHTML = value3;
  document.getElementById("value4").innerHTML = value4;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 20%;
}

.import {
  padding-bottom: 0.3em;
}

.import input[type=text] {
  width: 630px;
}

.valid {
  background-color: limegreen;
}

.invalid {
  background-color: red;
}

.imported_square {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.puzzle {
  border: 4px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.puzzle tr {
  padding: 0;
}

.puzzle td {
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 2em;
  font-size: 50pt;
  text-align: center;
}

.puzzle .thick_right {
  border-right: 4px solid black;
}

.puzzle .thick_bottom {
  border-bottom: 4px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button id="bt1">Rotate</button>
  <table class="puzzle" width=250px height=250px>
    <tr class="1 thick_bottom">
      <td id="value1" class="1 thick_right"></td>
      <td id="value2" class="2 thick_right"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="2 thick_bottom">
      <td id="value3" class="1 thick_right"></td>
      <td id="value4" class="2 thick_right"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use array.

```
<div>
  <button id="bt1">Rotate</button>
  <table class="puzzle" width=250px height=250px>
      <tr class="1 thick_bottom">
        <td id="value1" class="1 thick_right"></td>
        <td id="value2" class="2 thick_right"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="2 thick_bottom">
        <td id="value3" class="1 thick_right"></td>
        <td id="value4" class="2 thick_right"></td>
      </tr>
  </table>
  <script>
    var values = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];
    
    document.getElementById("value1").innerHTML = values[0];
    document.getElementById("value2").innerHTML = values[1];
    document.getElementById("value3").innerHTML = values[2];
    document.getElementById("value4").innerHTML = values[3];
    
    var btn = document.querySelector('#bt1');
    
    btn.addEventListener('click', rotate)
    var counter = 0;
    function rotate(){
        ++counter;
        document.getElementById("value1").innerHTML = values[(counter + 0)%4];
        document.getElementById("value2").innerHTML = values[(counter + 1)%4];
        document.getElementById("value3").innerHTML = values[(counter + 2)%4 ];
        document.getElementById("value4").innerHTML = values[(counter + 3)%4 ];
    }
  </script>
        <style type="text/css">
          body {
  font-family:sans-serif;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 20%;
          }
.import {padding-bottom:0.3em;}
.import input[type=text] {width:630px;}

.valid {background-color:limegreen;}
.invalid {background-color:red;}
.imported_square {background-color:lightgray;}

.puzzle {border:4px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;}
.puzzle tr {padding:0;}
.puzzle td {padding:0; border:1px solid black; width:2em; font-size:50pt; text-align:center;}
.puzzle .thick_right {border-right:4px solid black;}
.puzzle .thick_bottom {border-bottom:4px solid black;}
        </style>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
   var value1 = 1;
    var value2 = 2;
    var value4 = 3;
    var value3 = 4;

    document.getElementById("value1").innerHTML = value1;
    document.getElementById("value2").innerHTML = value2;
    document.getElementById("value3").innerHTML = value3;
    document.getElementById("value4").innerHTML = value4;

    var btn = document.querySelector('#bt1');

    btn.addEventListener('click', rotate)

    function rotate() {
        if(value1 === 1) {
            value1 = 4
        }else {
            value1--
        }

        if(value2 === 1) {
            value2 = 4
        }else {
            value2--
        }

        if(value3 === 1) {
            value3 = 4
        }else {
            value3--
        }

        if(value4 === 1) {
            value4 = 4
        }else {
            value4--
        }

        document.getElementById("value1").innerHTML = value1;
        document.getElementById("value2").innerHTML = value2;
        document.getElementById("value3").innerHTML = value3;
        document.getElementById("value4").innerHTML = value4;
        
    }
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 20%;
}

.import {
  padding-bottom: 0.3em;
}

.import input[type=text] {
  width: 630px;
}

.valid {
  background-color: limegreen;
}

.invalid {
  background-color: red;
}

.imported_square {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.puzzle {
  border: 4px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.puzzle tr {
  padding: 0;
}

.puzzle td {
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 2em;
  font-size: 50pt;
  text-align: center;
}

.puzzle .thick_right {
  border-right: 4px solid black;
}

.puzzle .thick_bottom {
  border-bottom: 4px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button id="bt1">Rotate</button>
  <table class="puzzle" width=250px height=250px>
    <tr class="1 thick_bottom">
      <td id="value1" class="1 thick_right"></td>
      <td id="value2" class="2 thick_right"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="2 thick_bottom">
      <td id="value3" class="1 thick_right"></td>
      <td id="value4" class="2 thick_right"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use loops and arrays in this case.

I didn't focus much on design. But this Javascript code will work on your script too.

```js
function rotate() {
  
 var array = []

  document.querySelectorAll('td').forEach((element) => {
    array.push(element.innerText)
  })

  array.push(array.shift())

  document.querySelectorAll('td').forEach((element, index) => {
    element.innerText = array[index]
  })
  
}
```

```css
table{
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table td{
  border: 2px solid #111;
  padding: 20px;
}

button{
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  background: #111;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button onclick='rotate()'>Rotate</button>
```

Comment: `shift()` itself doesn't immediately provide the desired clockwise or anti-clockwise rotation movement in a 2x2 table

Comment: @jjj shift() removes first element and using push() it is added to last. Moreover... instead of writing 10 lines extra, trial and error method is good.