# How can I control the move of blocks by a number I input in CSS and JS(or Vue)?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, frontend, vuejs3

My design is that all blocks are arranged in descending order by a number I input on the screen.when I reinput the number, an animation that the block goes up or down will appear.
The picture blow is more intuitive.
[image]

These blocks are generated by reading datas from the back end.

```
Chat.vue
<div  v-for="arr in data">
 <chatcard
   :id="arr.id"
   :weight="arr.weight"
   :content="arr.content"
   @msg="send"
 ></chatcard>
</div>
interface dataItem {
 id: number
 weight: number
 content: string
}
let data: dataItem[] = reactive([])
onMounted(()=>{


axios.get('/api/chat').then((res)=>{
    if(res.data.code===101){
      _.forEach(res.data.data,function(arr){
        data.push({
          id: arr.id,
          weight: arr.weight,
          content: arr.content
        })
      })
    }
  })
})
chatcard.vue

 <a-card class="card">
 <a-form>
      <a-form-item label="weight">
        <a-input v-model:value="weight"  style="width:100px"></a-input>
      </a-form-item>
      <a-form-item label="content">
        <a-textarea v-model:value="content" :rows="4" show-count :maxlength="1000" allow-clear/>

      </a-form-item>
      <a-form-item>
        <a-button type="primary" @click="submit">submit</a-button>
        <a-button  @click="del" danger>delete</a-button>
      </a-form-item>
    </a-form>
    </a-card>
    const weight=ref(0)
const content=ref('')

const info = defineProps({
  id: {
    type: String,
    default: ''
  },
  weight:  {
    type: Number,
    default:0,
  },
  content: {
    type: String,
    default: ''
  }
})

onMounted(()=>{
  weight.value=info.weight
  content.value=info.content
})

const emit = defineEmits(['msg'])

const submit=()=>{
  let paramm = {
    id: info.id,
    weight: info.weight,
    content: info.content
  }
  emit('msg', paramm)
}

const del=()=>{
  let paramm = {
    id: info.id,
    flag: 1
  }
  emit('msg', paramm)
}


  .card{
  width: 80vw;
  height: 250px;
  margin-left: 80px;
  background-color: white;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

The codes above is  part of my codes. To accomplish my effect, I need every chatcard's position, but where is it? And how do I get the distance of swaped chatcards?

Comment: I don't think you're going to accomplish this with pure CSS - is JavaScript on the table, or no?

Comment: Yes, not with pure CSS. My expression is not enough clear. Obviously, JavaScript is nessary. What confuses me is that I know the order, but I dont'know how to translate A to B and B to A. I use the Vue, chatcard is a children component and generated dynamicly. I don't know its  id and concrete position.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a CSS-only solution, I don't think this is possible (although I'm happy to be proven wrong by another poster).

One barebones way to do it would be using the CSS `order` property combined with a flexbox:

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 300px;
}

input{
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input oninput="this.style.order=this.value"/>
  <input oninput="this.style.order=this.value"/>
  <input oninput="this.style.order=this.value"/>
</div>
```

We subscribe to the `oninput` event here to update the order of the elements; this is a very minimal amount of JS.  This solution has the (potentially large) downside of not being possible to animate, so if you wanted to smoothly slide the elements up & down into their new positions, then you could look into a solution like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18846481/use-transition-on-flexbox-order), or a more in-depth JS solution involving absolute positioning with a transition on the `top`, like this:

```js
var inputs = [...document.querySelectorAll("input")];

function onInput(){
    inputs.sort((a, b) => (+a.value > 0 ? +a.value : 0) - (+b.value > 0 ? +b.value : 0));
  
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++)
  {
    inputs[i].style.top = (i * 50) + "px";
  }
}
```

```css
.container{
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

input{
  margin: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input oninput="onInput()" style="top: 0px"/>
  <input oninput="onInput()" style="top: 50px"/>
  <input oninput="onInput()" style="top: 100px"/>
</div>
```

You probably want to do some validation that the input is actually a number and not a string or other garbage, but hopefully this gets the idea across.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful advice. I find some inspiration.